# Trying to insert my own class into simple Java programme

Tags: java, class

There is a long code which "graphically simulates a bouncing ball", from the Stanford's YouTube series of lectures. In one of the [lectures](http://youtu.be/Iua9Klr0lfo?t=23m30s), the instructor changes the ball by using a class he created in advance (just change GOval for "GFace"), i.e. he makes the face bounce. I wanted to try this by creating my own class "gBox". So, instead of complicated "GFace", I just wanted to use a simple rectangle.
However, when I changed the GOval in the [source code](http://see.stanford.edu/materials/icspmcs106a/21-bouncing-ball-example.pdf) to "gBox" the following error occurs "The method move(int, int) in the type Component is not applicable for the arguments (double, double)".

I think I did something wrong with the class.

This is the class I wrote:

```
import acm.program.*;
import acm.graphics.*;

public class gBox extends GraphicsProgram{
    public void run(){
        GRect box = new GRect(50,50);
        add(box);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems your trying to pass `double` to an `int` type parameter. Instead of something like `move(10.0,25.0)` try to pass `move(10,25)`

Comment: I changed it as you suggested and it gave
"The method move(int, int) from the type Component is deprecated"

Comment: What is the definition of `GRect()`? Is it `GRect(double x, double y)` or is it `GRect(int x, int y)`?

Comment: pass it like move(50f,25f) to tell that it is float

Comment: user2408578, I tried what you suggested. Also, I tried writing (50.0 50.0) Still, the same error.

Comment: did you check the documentation? it seems to me that this function takes 4 parameters just looking from a quick check, all parameters seem to be ints

Comment: The statement "The method move(int, int) from the type Component is deprecated" is a warning indicating the method should no longer be used. Check the documentation for `move()` it will clearly indicate what data type to pass. This is not a cryptic problem.

Comment: Did you try running the code as it was before you made your modifications? I'm curious if this works fine for GOval or not on your machine.